# Keeps rows that aren't in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, isin

I have a dataframe with sales and offers.

```
df  offer                       sales
0   £10 off appple               10
1   £10 off apple and samsung    20
```

I have a list of offers that I want to avoid, which for this example has only 1 offer.

`remove_these_offers_list = ["£10 off appple"]`

When I try to remove this offer using
 `df.loc[~(df.offer.isin(remove_these_offers_list))]`
I get an empty df back because the string is technically contained in both rows.

Expected Output

```
df  offer                        sales
1   £10 off apple and samsung     20
```

Comment: I don't understand your description. `df.loc` doesn't remove anything. We can only tell you what is wrong with code that you actually show us.

Comment: well it is working on my side `df.loc[~(df.offer.isin(remove_these_offers_list))]`

Comment: So when you run that, you get a dataframe with the offer " £10 off apple and samsung". Doesn't isin work by partial string match?

Comment: isin always works on exact matches and str.contains works on partial matches(but you can also make it to work like full match by adding word boundary in the pattern)

Comment: its still doesnt work for me, not sure if its because im using pandas 1.2 not 1.3

Comment: Possibly that was due to the white spaces present in 'offer' column on either side since isin works on exact matches so maybe that's why you aren't getting required mask

Comment: Check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68716372/16343464) it is working fine. Your error was to use `loc`

Comment: @Anurag sorry I just see your comment now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try striping the white space by using `str.strip()`:

```
df=df.loc[~(df['offer'].str.strip().isin(remove_these_offers_list))]
```

OR

Since the method that you mentioned is working so another way via `str.fullmatch()`:

```
df=df.loc[~df['offer'].str.fullmatch('|'.join(remove_these_offers_list))]
```

output of `df`:

```
    df  offer                       sales
1   1   £10 off apple and samsung   20
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
df[~df['offer'].isin(remove_these_offers_list)]
```

isin should apply to the list, not the included strings, so only full matches should work